# Is there a convenient way to initialize std::pair<string, int>::second to 0?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
    vector<pair<const string, int>> v{ {"XXX", 0}, {"YYY", 0}, {"ZZZ", 0} };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].second << endl;
    }
```

Do I have to explicitly assign 0 for every element? Is there a convenient way to do this?

PS: To replace `0` with `{}` won't help.

Comment: I suspect an XY problem. What is the purpose of initializing these pairs? What's going to happen to this vector after it is initialized?

Comment: `{}` works well.

Comment: Does it have to be a pair? `struct StringInt { std::string name = ""; int amount = 0; };` solves the problem and leads to more readable code. Unless you have a good reason I would avoid pair.

Comment: When you want elements in a vector to be initialized with default values, just declare your vector using a constructor with one parameter which is the size of your vector. You didn't mention if you only want those string for the first elements in the pairs ("XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ").  They will be get the default value for a string, then you can set those values.

Answer (score 2):

Not too much good way, I give this solution,

```
    auto my_make_pair = [](string&& s)->pair<const string, unsigned> {
        return { s,0 };
    };
    vector<pair<const string, int>> v{ my_make_pair("XXX"), my_make_pair("YYY"), my_make_pair("ZZZ") };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].second << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

When you want elements in a `vector` to be initialized with `default values`, just declare your vector using a constructor with one parameter which is the size of your vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    constexpr uint8_t number_of_pairs{3}; // desired size
    vector<pair<const string, int>> v(number_of_pairs);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```